# tfs2005 shows pending edit

Tags: visual-studio-2005, tfs

I'm in Source Control Explorer 2005 and it shows I have some files in Pending edit status but I don't have any peding checkouts? Any ideas?

thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the same thing. In TFS when you checkout a file it is in pending status, until you check it in or undo your checkout. If you use TFS for a source control of course.